# Series pass transistor, LM7812

Tags: high-current, linear-regulator, lm78xx

I am making a 12 volt regulator for a solar panel to power an audio amplifier. I already have a switching regulator for most application but it is very noisy for amplifier even with a lot of filtering.
The amplifier draws over 3 amps on full load.

I want to build a regulator using 7812 with series pass transistor for higher current as shown in the datasheet, page 20.

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/LM7812-461970.pdf

I made the same circuit as shown in the datasheet and used the 2SD1047 as Q1

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/2sd1047.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBJDYQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But as I connected it to my bench power supply set to 18V I was not able to get a regulated output. It just showed ~2V less then the input voltage.

At 18V no load I got 16V output, 0.5A load 15V and 3A load 12V.
I tried different values of R1 calculated by the formula shown in the data sheet.

[image: Formula for R1]

**Is the output voltage affected by the the value of R1?
Please Help.**
[image: Beta of 2SD1047]
[image: Vbe]
While calculating R1 I assumed the value for Ireg to be 0.1A, Beta of transistor to be ~95, and IQ1 to be 3A, when that didn't work I tried a bunch of different values of resistors with the same results.

The LM7812 works great when no series pass transistor is attached.
And the transistor is good too.

I already have a switching regulator and I also have a higher current linear regulator so don't suggest them please. I want this circuit to work, and I also want to understand this circuit further so if you could point me to other learning material concerning this circuit then that would be great. The only thing I had to work with was the datasheet. Thanks

PS: SOLVED!! My mistake, I connected a NPN BJT instead of PNP.

Comment: Glad you could work out some issues yourself. Yes, with a 'boost' transistor a minimum load is needed so the Vbe is high enough. Major mistake though. The boost transistor MUST be a pnp, with the 12 volt current boost coming from the collector. Try a MJE172.

Comment: Oh Sorry!! I made such an obvious mistake and Thanks for not criticizing.

Comment: This is a really good question btw, quality-wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the diagram from page 20 of the datasheet you linked:

[image: Figure 13 from Fairchild LM78xx datasheet]

<sub>Image source: [Fairchild LM78xx datasheet, Figure 13](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/LM7812-461970.pdf)</sub>

Notice that the pass transistor is **PNP**. The mistake in your design, is that you are trying to use a [2SD1047](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/2sd1047.pdf) **NPN** pass transistor - which won't work, as you have seen.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and not making fun of me.

Comment: @HamzaKhan - No problem, and well done for writing a clear question and trying to solve the problem yourself :-) I see that you got the same reply in a comment, while I was typing this answer...

Comment: Keep in mind Q1 needs a heat sink of  ~ 2'C/W for 40'C rise @18Vin*3A so efficiency is 67%

Comment: @Hamza - Since you won't automatically be notified about the comment made by *Sunnyskyguy EE75*, I'm writing this comment, which *will* notify you. As he points out, one disadvantage of a linear regulator is that you have to dissipate all the heat from that series pass transistor. You say that your requirement is "over 3 amps max", so you will have to consider the heatsinking for that transistor and the regulator. If you need help with that topic, then feel free to ask a new question about it.